# How to convert xts timeseries to hourly difference from 00:00:00

Tags: r, timestamp, sequence, xts

I have an xts timeseries as

```
Timestamp           - X
30-07-2019 23:00:00 - 110
31-07-2019 00:00:00 - 120 
31-07-2019 01:00:00 - 105
31-07-2019 02:00:00 - 110 
31-07-2019 03:00:00 - 100 
31-07-2019 04:00:00 - 105 
31-07-2019 05:00:00 - 115 
31-07-2019 06:00:00 - 125
```

Now i want the timestamp to be the hours to be the hour of the day, for example

```
Timestamp - X
-1        - 110
0         - 120 
1         - 105
2         - 110 
3         - 100 
4         - 105 
5         - 115 
6         - 125
```

And still keep it as an xts series, in order to use it with dygraph in a shiny application

Comment: the xts 'index' ("timestamp") can't simply be the hour of the day. It needs to be of date-time format.  You could make a numeric column in the xts object that stores the hour of the timestamp though. atlerantively, make a data.frame/data.table for inputting to dygraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use `lubridate` approach:

```
library(lubridate)
hours_from_midnight <- hour(dmy_hms(df$Timestamp))
# boolean vector indicating if the time mome
after_midday <- pm(dmy_hms(df$Timestamp))
# coercion boolean to numerical is used
df$hour <- hours_from_midnight - 24 * after_midday
```

Comment: However note that this might not work with the dygraph as df$hour is not the index of the df

Answer (score 1):

Always try to provide your data in `dput` or in the way i have made the data

Here is the step by step way

```
Timestamp <- c("30-07-2019 23:00:00", "31-07-2019 00:00:00", "31-07-2019 01:00:00", "31-07-2019 02:00:00", "31-07-2019 03:00:00", "31-07-2019 04:00:00", "31-07-2019 05:00:00", "31-07-2019 06:00:00")
X <- c("-110","- 120","- 105","- 110","- 100","- 105","- 115","- 125")

#DF creation
df <- data.frame(Timestamp = Timestamp,X = X)

#Extracting `time` like `23:00:00`      
df$Timestamp <- sub(".* ", "", df$Timestamp)

#extracting only hours  
df$Timestamp <- format(strptime(df$Timestamp, format='%H:%M:%S'), '%H')

#converting into `Numeric` or `integer`
df$Timestamp <- as.integer(df$Timestamp)

#finally loop to get the desired result
for(i in df$Timestamp){
    if(i <= 12){
        df[,1][which(df$Timestamp == i)] <- i
    } else if(i > 12) {
        df[,1][which(df$Timestamp == i)] <- i-24
        } 
}
```

Output

```
Timestamp  X
-1        - 110
 0        - 120
 1        - 105
 2        - 110
 3        - 100
 4        - 105
 5        - 115
 6        - 125
```

EDIT:  concise way,this should also work

```
 df <- data.frame(Timestamp = Timestamp,X = X)

 #applying `POSIXct`
 df$Timestamp <- as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), "%H"))

 #loop
 df$Timestamp <- ifelse(df$Timestamp<=12,df$Timestamp,df$Timestamp-24)
```